# Can I use unsafecorce as hashkey/comaprison key for existential typeclass?

Tags: haskell, dictionary

So, if I want to create a hashmap key for example with the existential type like

```
data SomeId = forall a. SomeClass a => SomeId a
```

So, if I want to create a map I need to implement `Ord` myself. Is there a way to just store the value? And in this case, is `unsafeCooerce` to Int permanent or is there any caveat?

Like this?

```
instance Ord SomeId where
    compare (Id a) (Id b) = compare (unsafeCoerce a)::Int (unsafeCoerce b)::Int
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: A `HashMap` key doesn't need `Ord` - only a `Map`. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 5):

It isn't clear to me what you are looking for (and it may not be either to you). Here is how you can implement `Eq` and `Hashable` for your existential datatype.

You will need to add a `Hashable`, `Typeable`, and `Eq` constraint to the existential (in addition to whatever other constraints you wanted there in the first place - I'll use `Show`).

```
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Hashable

data SomeId = forall a. (Show a, Hashable a, Eq a, Typeable a) => SomeId a

-- This instance uses the fact 'SomeId' wraps types that have and 'Eq' and 
-- a 'Typeable' constraint
instance Eq SomeId where
  SomeId a == SomeId b = maybe False (a ==) (cast b)

-- This instance uses the fact 'SomeId' wraps types that have 'Hashable' constraints
instance Hashable SomeId where
  hashWithSalt s (SomeId a) = 0xdeadbeef * hashWithSalt s a
```

And, for debugging purposes:

```
instance Show SomeId where
  show (SomeId x) = show x
```

Now, I can use `SomeId` as the key in a `HashMap`. For example,

```
ghci> import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as H
ghci> hashMap = H.fromList [(SomeId 1, "one"), (SomeId (), "unit"), (SomeId "s", "string")]
ghci> H.lookup (SomeId 1) hashMap
Just "one"
ghci> H.lookup (SomeId ()) hashMap
Just "unit"
ghci> H.lookup (SomeId "s") hashMap
Just "string
ghci> H.lookup (SomeId 2) hashMap
Nothing
ghci> H.lookup (SomeId True) hashMap
Nothing
```

As a final remark: note that of the initial constraints you are putting on `SomeId`, `Typeable` and `Eq` are both derivable so satisfying those bounds isn't nearly as difficult as it may seem initially.

---

In case it isn't clear, I am showing you an alternative to your `unsafeCoerce`. That approach is... not advisable. In particular, it

- violates referential transparency in general
- completely disregards all of the laws for `Eq` and `Ord`

In short - it won't work, and even if it did it would create a whole host of difficult to replicate and confusing errors.

Comment: Why I did not consider forwarding to the type's own `Eq` I do not know.... sometimes we're too attached to something being hard

Comment: @luqui Been there too. :) On a separate note, `hetero-map`  is pretty neat. Nice use of rank 2 types.

Answer (score 4):

This is awful and you absolutely should not do this.  The `unsafeCoerce` here could return different values depending on whether the expression has been evaluated yet, if GC decides to move the object (and GHC has a compacting collector AFAIK, so that will happen all the time), maybe even depend on objects that have nothing to do with it by reading past the end.  Terrible, terrible idea, this.

Referential equality tests, like you see in most imperative languages

```
var foo = Object();
var bar = Object();
foo === foo   // true
foo === bar   // false
```

are not possible in Haskell, because of *referential transparency*, which says that you can always substitute a variable with its definition and nothing will change.  If the language which shall not be named had referential transparency, you could replace that code with:

```
 Object() === Object()  // true
 Object() === Object()  // false
```

which is clearly a contradiction.  Referential transparency is one of the things that makes Haskell so nice to work with, but unfortunately, if I'm inferring what you're trying to do, it's going to make it impossible.  I recommend against circumventing referential transparency (which you can do using `unsafePerformIO`) -- Haskell is *extremely* hard to reason about without it -- the whole language is built around that assumption.

So with that caveat, here are some notes anyhow for funzies, since I have been down this particular rabbit hole.

It looks to me like you're modeling a map from `Id`s to the objects they refer to, and this map can be polymorphic.  I.e. maybe you want functions like:

```
insert :: SomeClass a => a -> MyMap -> (SomeId, MyMap)
lookup :: MyMap -> SomeId -> ???
```

with some suitable value of `???` which is impossible because we have forgotten the type information.  You could use [`Data.Dynamic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html), I suppose:

```
lookup :: MyMap -> SomeId -> Maybe Dynamic
```

Depending on what you want to do.  This is going to involve a lot of casting and you are basically throwing static type safety out the window by doing this.

Maybe you want to consider typed identifiers?

```
insert :: SomeClass a => a -> MyMap -> (SomeId a, MyMap)
lookup :: MyMap -> SomeId a -> Maybe a
```

If you have `SomeClass` require some *unique* "hash" generation function (and it is really guaranteed to be unique even across types) then you can make this API work.  If there is a collision, then you get a bad `unsafeCoerce` error (e.g. try `unsafeCoerce 42 "foo" :: String` in ghci).  You can ease some of that pain by adding a [`TypeRep`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#t:TypeRep) into your Id type, but you'll still have to decide how to hash the values yourself.

You could pair the value with a freshly generated [`Unique`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Unique.html) when you make the key, using `unsafePerformIO`, but you will violate referential transparency if you do this, since if you generate two keys with the same value, they will compare different, which is nonsense in a pure language.

Basically, the whole idea of a heterogeneous map is fraught with difficulty.

I wrote [`hetero-map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hetero-map) which implements a type-safe heterogeneous map, more as an art piece about how frivolous the idea is than a useful module.   But hey, let me know if you find use out of it. ;-)

Maybe you should take a step back and describe the larger problem you are trying to solve such that you feel you need this.  I assure you there is a better way.